# Javascript help regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with a javascript regex because I can't figure it out.
The regex needs the following criteria:

1. Minimum 3 characters
2. Maximum 40 characters
3. Contains only letters, numbers a whitespace (no newline and other characters like ?,_,...)
4. CAN contain ONLY 1 *, but after 3 characters

Here's some testdata:

- I am some testdata     -> OK
- I am * some testdata   -> OK
- I*am some testdata     -> NOK (* after 3 characters)
- I am * some * testdata -> NOK ( 0 or 1 times a *)
- I am some testdata and I am much longer than the maximum -> NOK (to long)
- AB                     -> NOK (not long enough)

Because I'm not a pro at creating a regex, this is what I collected so far (but I can't put them together):

- /[^\S\n]/   -> Only whitespace and no newline
- /[\w]/      -> Word character
- {3,40}      -> Between 3 and 40 characters

Comment: Can the * occur anywhere after 3 chars? or only in the 4th pos?

Comment: Consider points 1, 3, 4 to come up with a regex; then adapt it to satisfy #2.

Comment: The * can occur anywhere after 3 chars!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work for you for all conditions:

```
^(?!.{1,2}?\*)(?!(?:.*?\*){2})[\w .?*,]{3,40}$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eJ3aF7

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?=.{,40}$)[A-Za-z0-9\s]{3,}\*?[A-Za-z0-9\s]*$/
```